# Windows Phone 7 mango use Audio stream

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I would like to know how do I use Audio stream. I am interested to make sound in most efficient way ,

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read this when I do my project, you can check it out:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2010/11/Playing-Music-Files-on-WP7.html